# Question marked as active today, with no activity on it today

Tags: bug

I keep seeing old questions on the homepage that don't seem to have any recent activity on them. Like [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/398698/how-to-optimize-a-binary-circuit) for instance, which was on the home page and *claims* to have been last active today, but nothing has been edited or commented since 2018. What, exactly, is the activity that brought this question to the home page?

It's not just this one either--I've seen dozens if not hundreds of cases of this over the past few months. And they don't have the message "bumped to the home page by community" that they get when they automatically get bumped up, so it doesn't seem to be an automatic thing. Unless they removed that message? If so, that's a bit confusing.

Putting the "bug" tag on this because the tag description says it's for "erroneous or unexpected behavior", and I'd call this unexpected. I hope that's not the wrong tag to use.

Answer (score 2):

I've also seen that. I think it *used* to be that those posts had "Bumped by Community" written on them or something similar, but that message is no longer shown.

If you look at the new [timeline](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/398698/timeline) for your post you can see that the most recent event was that it was indeed "bumped" by Community. (It can be reached by clicking on the little "clock"-looking icon under the vote buttons)

Comment: Aha. Strange that it no longer shows that message--I feel like it should show *something* to indicate why this random question is on the front page suddenly.

Comment: @Hearth From the front page, it shows "modified x hours ago Community ♦" for the bumped questions, so you can quickly identify them. From the post itself, it's true there doesn't seem to be a quick way to check the activity was caused by an automatic bump anymore, and I agree that is annoying. Here is the explanation about that on the main meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340295/wheres-the-bump-notice